# hiding tkinter window using withdraw vs wm_withdraw

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

What is the difference between `withdraw` and `wm_withdraw`?

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

def hide():
    root.withdraw()
    time.sleep(2)
    root.deiconify()

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text = 'hide', command = hide).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When the 'hide' button is clicked, the window is hidden. It disappears from the panel (taskbar), and is not visible in the task view (simultaneous view of all open windows) for 2 seconds.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

def hide():
    root.wm_withdraw()
    time.sleep(2)
    root.deiconify()

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text = 'hide', command = hide).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Same code, but `wm_withdraw` instead of `withdraw`. Again, clicking the 'hide' button makes the both the taskbar entry and the window itself invisible for 2 seconds.

Is there any difference at all between these two? Which one should I use? Further, should I use `deiconify` or `wm_deiconify`? All four combinations (`withdraw`, `deiconify`; `wm_withdraw`, `deiconify`; `withdraw`, `wm_deiconify`; `wm_withdraw`, `wm_deiconify`) seem to do the exact same thing. Is there any application where they will do different things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between them - they both ([withdraw](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2233) and [deiconify](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L2006)) just shortucts for `wm_` counterparts.

The same applies to all functions, that interact with Window manager under [Wm class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1932).

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between withdraw and wm_withdraw. I can not specify why this was done, but here is the source of tkinter in which we have line `withdraw = wm_withdraw` (which makes it clear that both calls end up at the same method):

```
def wm_withdraw(self):
    """Withdraw this widget from the screen such that it is unmapped
    and forgotten by the window manager. Re-draw it with wm_deiconify."""
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'withdraw', self._w)
withdraw = wm_withdraw
```